# BulletSpan color and gap

Tags: android, richtext

I have to handle some RichText inside a TextiView with Android. The problem I have is that I need to set a list style which means add a bullet and and a gap. To do this, I parse my richText by implementing the HTML.TagHandler interface. Here is my code for the bullet/gap:

```
                if (!opening && tagOpened(tag))
                {
                    int start = tagOpeningPosition(tag);
                    if (start < output.length())
                    {
                        if (!Tags.UL.equals(mPreviousTag))
                        {
                            output.append("\n");
                        }
                        output.append("\n");
                        output.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan.Standard(35, 35), start, output.length(), 0);
                        output.setSpan(new BulletSpan(0, Color.parseColor("#D4007A")), start, output.length(), 0);
                    }
                }
```

The issue is that on some Androids, I have a black bullet and no gap, and on some others, I have the bullet with the right color and the gap.
I tried on a Nexus 5 with Android 6.0 and it's working, and on a OnePlus5 with Android 7.0 it's not.
So I'm wondering if there is a solution to make it work on every devices and have the same render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved:** Some Android versions seem to not detect ul/li tags with HTML.tagHandler. The workaround I found was to replaceAll ul/li with custom tags. Those custom tags are detected by the tagHandler.